# CardView selected background color in RecyclerView

Tags: android

i am trying to write a RecyclerView with CardViews and using CAB trying to delete multiple Cards on selection .How do i give background color to the selected cards. i am trying to use statelistdrawable as the following :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/primary_dark" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

and apply it to the CardView layout as :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"


    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:tag="image_tag"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/one"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

below is the code for my adapter

```
public class modeladapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<modeladapter.myholder> {

    ArrayList<MyModel> arraylist;
SparseBooleanArray selecteditems;
    public modeladapter(ArrayList<MyModel> ar) {
        arraylist=ar;
        selecteditems=new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    public void removeData(int position) {
        arraylist.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public MyModel getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    public void addData(MyModel newModelData, int position) {
        arraylist.add(position, newModelData);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        if (selecteditems.get(pos, false)) {
            selecteditems.delete(pos);
        }
        else {
            selecteditems.put(pos, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public void clearSelections() {
        selecteditems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selecteditems.size();
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
        List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>(selecteditems.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < selecteditems.size(); i++) {
            items.add(selecteditems.keyAt(i));
        }
        return items;
    }





    @Override
    public modeladapter.myholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater lf=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

            View v = lf.inflate(R.layout.card_lay, viewGroup, false);

//            v.setOnClickListener(Activity_Main.listener);
            myholder m=new myholder(v);
            return m;



    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(modeladapter.myholder m, int i) {

                m.cimage.setImageResource(arraylist.get(i).url);
                m.email.setText(arraylist.get(i).email);
                m.name.setText(arraylist.get(i).name);
m.itemView.setActivated(selecteditems.get(i,false));

         }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()  {return (arraylist.size());}

    public static class myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView cimage;
        TextView name,email;

        public myholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cimage= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            email= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            if(itemView.isActivated())
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
            else
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }
```

kindly update how i can change the background color of selected items.
thanks

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @JaredBurrows i was able to do so.

Comment: @JaredBurrows  gave me some idea as to how it could be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to have a `StateListDrawable`
You need to have a method in your adapter that checks for selections:

```
sparseArray.valueAt(i).isSelected()
```

Then in your `RecylcerView.Adapter`, change:

```
if (itemView.isActivated())
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
else
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

To(You need to change the cardView, not the itemView):

```
 viewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(sparseArray.valueAt(i).isSelected() ? Color.LTGRAY : Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: where is the method to check for selections located in the Adapter?  in the ViewHolder() or onBindViewHolder()?  Can you edit above to show an example.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone new to this issues, it's worth noting as of support library v24, the CardView now supports a ColorStateList.  (Note: this is a color state list, not a drawable state list)

Here's the link:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78198

Comment: So suppose I want to add a selectable color to what it has, how do I do this?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Take a look at your answer below ;)  (I'm guessing you posted your answer after this comment...)

Comment: It's more of a workaround. I was hoping you have a more official, better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/statelist_item_background"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the CardView background color, 
change the LinearLayout inside the CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:tag="image_tag"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/one"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?
            android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it. Here's how to do it programmatically:

Use your own custom card view:

```
class SelectableCardView : MaterialCardView {
    @ColorInt
    private var unselectedBackgroundColor = 0

    @ColorInt
    private var selectedBackgroundColor = 0

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        unselectedBackgroundColor = cardBackgroundColor.defaultColor
        setCardBackgroundColor(ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), IntArray(0)), intArrayOf(selectedBackgroundColor, unselectedBackgroundColor)))
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        unselectedBackgroundColor = cardBackgroundColor.defaultColor
        setCardBackgroundColor(ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), IntArray(0)), intArrayOf(selectedBackgroundColor, unselectedBackgroundColor)))
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        unselectedBackgroundColor = cardBackgroundColor.defaultColor
        setCardBackgroundColor(ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), IntArray(0)), intArrayOf(selectedBackgroundColor, unselectedBackgroundColor)))
    }

    init {
        selectedBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color....)
    }
}
```

Or when inflating, set the color yourself from outside:

```
val cardView = result!!.cardView
val selectedBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(inflater.context, R.color....)
val unselectedBackgroundColor = cardView .cardBackgroundColor.defaultColor
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), IntArray(0)),intArrayOf(selectedBackgroundColor, unselectedBackgroundColor)))
```

Of course, you could set the card background color set via XML, but then you would have to have the default one also being set. I don't recommend it because it might change in the future, as it was recently.

For example, in the past is was `cardview_dark_background` and changed to `design_dark_default_color_background` on dark theme, and was `cardview_light_background` and changed to `design_default_color_background` on normal theme.